# Binary tree can't get to print long branch

Tags: java

I'm doing a homework assignment about binary trees but I cant get to print its long branch.
Here's my main:

```
Arbol arbol = new Arbol();
arbol.Inserta(45);
arbol.Inserta(20);
arbol.Inserta(30);
arbol.Inserta(25);
arbol.Inserta(61);
arbol.Inserta(90);
arbol.Inserta(33);
arbol.Inserta(82);
arbol.Inserta(18);
arbol.Inserta(50);
arbol.Inserta(35);
arbol.Inserta(32);
arbol.imprimeRamaLarga();
```

Then the method.

```
public void imprimeRamaLarga() {
    if (Raiz != null) {
        cont = 0;
        cont2 = 0;
        imprimeRamaLargaRec(Raiz);
    } else {
        System.out.println("El arbol esta vacio.");
    }
}
private void imprimeRamaLargaRec(Nodo n) {
    if (n != null) {
        if (cont >= cont2) {
            cont++;                               
            imprimeRamaLargaRec(n.getHijoIzq());       
            imprimeRamaLargaRec(n.getHijoDer());                
            cont--;                 
            cont2++;   
            if (cont <= cont2) {
            System.out.println(n.getId());                   
            }             
        } 
    }
}
```

It gets to print all the other elements of the branch but I can't get to print the last one which it would be "32" the rest it prints it right.

This is my inserting method.

```
private Nodo Raiz;
public void Inserta(int num) {
    if (Raiz == null) {
        Raiz = new Nodo(num);
    } else {
        InsertaRec(Raiz, num);
    }
}

private void InsertaRec(Nodo n, int num) {
    if (num <= n.getId()) {
        if (n.getHijoIzq() == null) {
            n.setHijoIzq(new Nodo(num));
        } else {
            InsertaRec(n.getHijoIzq(), num);
        }
    } else {
        if (n.getHijoDer() == null) {
            n.setHijoDer(new Nodo(num));
        } else {
            InsertaRec(n.getHijoDer(), num);
        }
    }
}
```

And if you are wondering which is the Nodo class this is it.

```
public class Nodo {

private int id;
private Nodo HijoIzq;
private Nodo HijoDer;

public Nodo(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Nodo getHijoIzq() {
    return HijoIzq;
}

public void setHijoIzq(Nodo HijoIzq) {
    this.HijoIzq = HijoIzq;
}

public Nodo getHijoDer() {
    return HijoDer;
}

public void setHijoDer(Nodo HijoDer) {
    this.HijoDer = HijoDer;
}
```

Comment: Which order are you trying to print in? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: Also, what are `cont` and `cont2`?

Comment: It doesn't matter the order.
But the order I get is: 
35
33
30
20
45

It should print "32" just before 35. 
>cont
 and 
>cont2 they are 2 int counters I don't know why but they help. I can't use any library btw.

Comment: Can you add the rest of your Arbol class, or are you sure the insert method is working correctly?

Comment: There you go thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the longest branch, you can either find the branch then print it or print the side that have the largest deep:

The one I found easy to implement is printing the side that have the largest deep: soo first we need the a function to find the deep of a `Nodo`.

```
public int getDeep(Nodo n){
    if(n == null)
        return 0;

    int dd = getDeep(n.getHijoDer() );
    int di = getDeep(n.getHijoIzq() );

    return 1 + (dd > di ? dd : di);
}
```

Using the `getDeep(Nodo n)` I come to this solution:

```
private void imprimeRamaLargaRec(Nodo n) {
    if (n != null) {
        int dd = getDeep(n.getHijoDer() );//deep for the right child
        int di = getDeep(n.getHijoIzq() );//deep for the left child

        if(dd > di){
            imprimeRamaLargaRec(n.getHijoDer() );
        }else{
            imprimeRamaLargaRec(n.getHijoIzq() );
        }
        System.out.println(n.getId());  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! It worked the way I wanted! Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

You need two traversals through the tree.

First find longest branch - set `max` to `0` and whenever count (`depth`) is higher reset `max` to `depth`

On the second run use variables `cont` (`false`) and `depth` and set `cont` to `true` only once your current `depth` reaches previously gathered `max`. Then start printing while traversing through your recursion back.

Comment: How whould u do it? I cant use any for or while. I have another method that gaves me the depth so im using it to return me the depth. But still dk how.

Comment: Don't need two traversals through the tree to get depth, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote a quick Tree class myself from scratch. It's been awhile since I've done it, but it seems to work, so here's what I have. Hopefully it is helpful to you! Sorry for not translating.

#### Main.java

Nothing out of the ordinary here.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();

        for (int i : Arrays.asList(45, 20, 30, 25, 61, 90, 33, 82, 18, 50, 35, 32)) {
            tree.insert(i);
        }

        System.out.println("Longest Branch: ");
        tree.printLongBranch();

        System.out.println("\nPre Order: ");
        tree.printPreOrder();

        System.out.println("\nIn Order: ");
        tree.printInOrder();
    }
}
```

#### Output

> Longest Branch:
>   45 20 30 33 32 35
>   Pre Order:
>   45 20 18 30 25 33 32 35 61 50 90 82
>   In Order:
>   18 20 25 30 32 33 35 45 50 61 82 90

#### Node.java

Just the basics. I trust you understand recursion, so if my insert method looks weird, just run though it by hand and you'll see what it is doing. The two methods at the bottom show 2 different traversals, in-order and pre-order.

```
public class Node {
    private int data;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;
    private int height = 1;

    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }

    public Node insert(int data) {
        int leftHeight = 0;
        int rightHeight = 0;

        if (data <= this.getData()) {
            if (left == null) {
                this.left = new Node(data);
            } else {
                left = left.insert(data);
            }
            leftHeight = left.getHeight();
        } else if (data > this.getData()) {
            if (right == null) {
                this.right = new Node(data);
            } else {
                this.right = right.insert(data);
            }
            rightHeight = right.getHeight();
        }

        this.height = 1 + Math.max(leftHeight, rightHeight);
        return this;
    }

    public void printLongBranch() {
        int leftHeight = left == null ? 0 : left.getHeight();
        int rightHeight = right == null ? 0 : right.getHeight();

        System.out.print(this.data + " ");

        if (rightHeight == leftHeight) {
            if (left != null) {
                left.printLongBranch();
            }
            if (right != null) {
                right.printLongBranch();
            }
        }
        else if (leftHeight > rightHeight) {
            if (left != null) {
                left.printLongBranch();
            }
        } else {
            if (right != null) {
                right.printLongBranch();
            }
        }
    }

    public void printInOrder() {
        if (this.left != null) {
            this.left.printInOrder();
        }

        System.out.print(this.data + " ");

        if (this.right != null) {
            this.right.printInOrder();
        }
    }

    public void printPreOrder() {
        System.out.print(this.data + " ");

        if (this.left != null) {
            this.left.printPreOrder();
        }

        if (this.right != null) {
            this.right.printPreOrder();
        }
    }

}
```

#### BinaryTree.java

Nothing complicated here either.

```
public class BinaryTree {
    private Node root;

    public void insert(int data) {
        if (this.root == null) {
            this.root = new Node(data);
        } else {
            this.root = this.root.insert(data);
        }
    }

    public void printInOrder() {
        this.root.printInOrder();
    }

    public void printPreOrder() {
        this.root.printPreOrder();
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return this.root.getHeight();
    }

    public void printLongBranch() {
        this.root.printLongBranch();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you but is not what im looking for. I have those methods too but what I'm trying to get is to print the long brench of the tree! But thank you!

Comment: @FaridR - Ahh, I see what you're asking now after drawing the tree :)

Comment: Haha Yeah well thank you for your time and help! The other guy solved it!

Comment: @FaridR - Yeah he beat me to it, but my updated solution is a one-pass solution since I calculate the height during insertion.